# Translation for "There are 20 students in my class"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> There are 20 students in my class.

I've read the thread on [difference between es gibt/es sind](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/difference-between-es-sind-and-es-gibt-for-asserting-existence-of-something), and since this example is a specific situation, it seems the translation should be

> Es sind 20 Schüler in meiner Klasse.

Is that a correct translation? What would be some other alternatives?

Comment: Are you aware that "Schüler" means pupils?

Comment: @unor in American English even an elementary school has students, not pupils, so the translation may be spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common translation would be

> In meiner Klasse sind 20 Schüler.

Or

> Bei mir sind 20 Schüler in der Klasse.

Another possibility is

> In meiner Klasse hat es 20 Schüler.

One would not use "es gibt" in that case because the sentence is only about the number of students while "es gibt" focusses more if an object exists or not. 
A more formal version would be
"Meine Klasse besteht aus 20 Schülern. "
But thats not something one would say in spoken language.

Comment: You could complete your answer by providing "some other alternatives".

Comment: But "Es sind 20 Schüler in meiner Klasse." is a correct translation, too. Isn't it?

Comment: "Es sind 20 Schüler in meiner Klasse" is a totally correct translation.

Comment: "In meiner Klasse hat es 20 Schüler" sounds *totally* wrong in my ears.

Comment: The expression „hat es“ is used only in some regions of Germany.

Comment: The "Es sind..." version is the same as the first one here, just with "in meiner Klasse" moved. The "es" is just a grammatical filler

Comment: *Es hat* is German, but not standard German.

Answer (score 0):

> Es sind 20 Schüler in meiner Klasse.

Is a totally fine translation.

> In meiner Klasse hat es 20 Schüler

well, this is colloquial in some regions but not standard German... (it would translate back to something like: *there in my class have 20 students*).

Comment: This seems to have been meant as a comment on user9298's answer.