# What is the etymology of "Es gibt" in the sense of "There is"?

Tags: verb, etymology

What is the etymology of "Es gibt" in the sense of the English "There is/There are"?

In English, "There is" is used to indicate the existence of something abstract of physical, though as I understand it, "Es gibt" is generally used for more abstract concepts ([link](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/difference-between-es-sind-and-es-gibt-for-asserting-existence-of-something)). That said, I still find the use of the verb "geben" to be quite odd.

Looking at the translations for ["There is" on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_is), the vast majority of the languages there either use the equivalent of the verbs "to be / sein" or "to have / haben" in their expressions for something existing. In fact, aside from the few languages that have a dedicated word for this concept, German was the only one I could find that used a verb other than "to be" or "to have".

So how did the phrase "Es gibt" come to have the meaning of something (abstract) existing?

Comment: This is in no way reserved for abstract concepts, you can equally well use the expression for concrete concepts. As a side note, in Swedish we use "det finns" which means  "there is to be found" to say exactly the same thing.

Comment: "Es gibt" can be used for concrete objects too, "Es gibt Leute, die..." (There are people who...). The word 'give' can also have the sense of existence. As far as the origin of the phrase, I don't know.

Comment: In Chinese you use "have," with no subject.

Comment: In South-Western Germany's dialects, *es hat* is indeed used as a synonym for *es gibt*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a gradual development from the Germanic and Old High German`geban` in the meaning of *to give* to the peculiar abstract usage *es gibt* which only occured in New High German.

There is quite an elaborate essay on almost all meanings and their etymology of [*geben* in Grimm's dictionary](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG02642#XGG02642). It would be beyond the scope of an answer here to fully translate this but let me try to give you the essence of what they believed was the origin of *es gibt.*

One meaning of *geben* is to give something away but also give it into somebodies hands. On crafting this hand can produce something as a result (*ergeben*). Later the "hand" was omitted to just leave the meaning of *to make sth., to result in sth.*. This also took place in English:

> Die Sonne gibt Licht (*The sun gives light*)

Now in a next step the subject was further abstracted and initially was replaced by *dies* or *das*.

> **Disz gab** allerlei Reden am Tische. <sup>Luther</sup>
>     **Das** wird eine schöne Geschichte **geben**, sagte das liebe Mädchen. <sup>Goethe</sup>

Later *dies* and *das* were further reduced to an integrating and indefinite ***es*** and at the same time the original meaning of *geben* (*to give*) became more and more obscure:

> Wann man Pulver auf die Pfanne schüttet und die Lunte aufsetzet, so **gibt es** einen großen Knall. <sup>Schuppius</sup>
>    Sie *(die Kugel)* ist von Thon, **es gibt** Scherben. <sup>Göthe</sup>

Comment: Wow. That was an answer of a quality I would like to see more often here! Thank you!

Comment: In addition to this good answer, I want to add *da ist* und *da haben* are still an option for a number of cases. And then there is the verb *ergeben* of which one meaning is *to give a result*.

Comment: @Janka: yeah - we could endlessly elaborate this... and of course all variations still coexist until today (only *es gibt* developed last), The verb *ergeben* is already mentioned, perhaps a bit hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that this might have been originally intended to be translated as "**it is given**". Perhaps "by God" or "by nature". God gave it and now it is there.

Comment: Müsste es dann nicht mit "It was given" übersetzt werden?

Answer (score 0):

In North American colloquial English, we can say "What gives?" to mean "Whatʹs going on?"  To which "Es gibt ..." seems like a similar concept.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31160/etymology-of-what-gives